# BouncyCastle HMAC SHA1

Tags: c#, bouncycastle, hmac, hmacsha1

I have the following code using BouncyCastle (dotnet version) to get a HMAC-SHA1 from a message.

I have this small library class:

```
public class HashingTools
{
    static string hmacKey = "81310910a060c5705c1d3cedf370bcf9";
    public static int HashSizeInBytes = 20;
    static KeyParameter keyParameter = null;
    private static HMac hmacInstance;

    static HashingTools()
    {
        hmacInstance = new HMac(new Sha1Digest());
        hmacInstance.Init(newKeyParameter(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(hmacKey)));
    }

    public static byte[] HashSha1(byte[] message)
    {
        byte[] result = new byte[hmacInstance.GetMacSize()];

        hmacInstance.BlockUpdate(message, 0, message.Length);
        hmacInstance.DoFinal(result, 0);

        return result;
    }
}
```

And I have a lot of messages going through this method, all using the same key: `hmacKey`, and I would like to speed it up as much as I can, and reuse as much as I can, still with respect to security parameters (randomness, freshness...).

If I try to reuse or parallellize the `hmac` instance, I get an "array out of bounds" exception inside `Org.BouncyCastle.Crypto.Macs.Hmac.BlockUpdate`.

I've created this unittest for reproduction (1 or 2 parallel hash functions goes fine, 100 goes wrong):

```
[Test]
public void TestBulkHashing()
{
    var messages = new List<byte[]>();

    foreach (var index in Enumerable.Range(0, 100))
    {
        var buffer = new byte[4096];
        Random r = new Random();
        r.NextBytes(buffer);

        messages.Add(buffer);
    }

    Parallel.ForEach(messages, m =>
    {
        HashingTools.HashSha1(m);
    });
}
```

Comment: Cannot reproduce, I get no exception. Edit your question to include the code that **doesn't work**, and the full stack trace of the exception.

Comment: I've edited my question to include how to reproduce.

Comment: the appearance of the keyword `static` alone is questionable. something sharing internal static states is the very reason why something is or isn't thread-safe. some links that might lead somewhere: [bouncycastle](http://bouncy-castle.1462172.n4.nabble.com/Is-signing-or-encryption-operation-thread-safe-when-each-thread-creates-its-own-Signature-or-Cipher--td1468286.html), [and this](https://7thzero.com/blog/threadsafe-bouncy-castle-c-lightweight-api) - `System.Random` might not be thread-safe either. [also this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49473/is-bouncy-castle-api-thread-safe)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As correctly surmised by @dlatikay, this is a synchronization mistake. Bouncycastle's classes are not thread-safe unless they explicitly say it is.

If you modify your `HashSha1` method to explicitly synchronize threads you will not get the exception:

```cs
public static byte[] HashSha1(byte[] message) {
    byte[] result = new byte[hmacInstance.GetMacSize()];
    lock(hmacInstance) {
        hmacInstance.BlockUpdate(message, 0, message.Length);
        hmacInstance.DoFinal(result, 0);
    }

    return result;
}
```

As to your question about optimization, Bouncycastle already pre-computes the part of the computation that involves the key. When you call `DoFinal(...)` the internal state is reset to this pre-computed value so you do not need to call `Init()` again for the next HMac if you use the same key. Your code already takes advantage of this optimization so I don't think there is more you can do unless you want to write your own hashing code.